# MySQL creating table on references error

Tags: mysql

I followed this guide: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

I keep getting this error when I try to create the second table, but I can't find any syntax errors.

```
CREATE TABLE articles (
    id int UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE articles_images (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    article_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    image_url VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    INDEX fk_ix_articles_images$articles (article_id),
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (article_id)
        REFERENCES articles(id)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
```

The error I find is

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'CES articles(id)  UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE
>   RESTRICT )' at line 8

Comment: It works fine for me on Mysql 5.7

Comment: What's the db engines on these 2 tables?

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot.

I've used tabs instead of spaces and something glitches out if the query is copied with tabs instead of spaces directly into the shell.